# ASP.NET/C# Decimal to 0.00

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal

I got this method, how can I make the decimal to .00 and not .0000?

```
    public static List<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Products";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Product product = new Product();
                    product.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
                    product.ManufacturerId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ManufacturerId"]);
                    product.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CategoryId"]);
                    product.Name = (reader["Name"]).ToString();
                    product.Description = (reader["Description"]).ToString();
                    product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]);
                    product.ItemsInStock = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemsInStock"]);

                    products.Add(product);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return products;
}
```

UPDATE:
Sorry for asking stupid questions.
I can't see where to put the DataFormatString="{0:F2}"

This is my grid:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown where you are displaying these.  All we have is a database cell and an object in memory, both of which are merely storage.  For storage purposes, `.00` and `.0000` are *the same thing.*   Trying to translate from one to the other is a waste of resources.  Show us where you display this to the user, and we'll help you format it however you want.

Also, as a personal preference I'd write that code like this:

```
private static ToProduct(this IDataRecord record)
{
    var product = new Product();
    product.Id = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal("Id"));
    product.ManufacturerId = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal("ManufacturerId"));
    product.CategoryId = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal("CategoryId"));
    product.Name = record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("Name"));
    product.Description = record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("Description"));
    product.Price = record.GetDecimal(record.GetOrdinal("Price"));
    product.ItemsInStokc = record.GetInt32(record.GetOrdinal("ItemsInStock"));
    return product;
}

public static IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Products";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return reader.ToProduct();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
You commented that this will be in a GridView.  Okay.  In that case, all you need to do is have a `DataFormatString` in the column definition, like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="TestView" ... >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataFormatString="{0:F2}"  />
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: As an aside, this demonstrates one of the few things I like better about visual basic.  Imagine for a moment that this is last method in the last class in a namespace.  The end of the file would have 6 nested closing braces (}). The VB ends up so much easier to read.

Comment: Sorry i am printing this to a GridView.
i can't use product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"].ToString("0.00")); because it expects an integer

Comment: What "solution"?  I haven't told you how to fix your problem yet.  Only that you're looking at the wrong thing to fix it.  But we are getting somewhere.  You want to show this in a gridview.  Great!  Now we know how to fix the display issue.  I'll update my answer to explain what you need to do.

Answer (score 5):

1234m.ToString("0.00")

Answer (score 1):

When printing Product.Price, use .ToString("N2").  What you might want is the full currency expression, which is .ToString("C").  Here is a reference link for all the format strings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously you couldn't do the following

```
product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]).ToString("0.00");
```

as it would return a string. Though you may beable to do this:

```
product.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"].ToString("0.00"));
```

This would seem the most logical way to complete this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried about culture settings?

Check out this msdn link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Should hopefully give you a hand.